# Bulk update technique in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my mysql db. I deactivating users with login date older than 2 days

```
// users
--------------------------
| id | user     | active |  // + 10 other fields
--------------------------
| 1  | John Doe | 1      |
| 2  | Ron Gore | 1      |
--------------------------

// login
-----------------------------
| id | user_id | date       |
| 1  | 1       | 2014-11-10 |
| 2  | 2       | 2014-11-03 |
-----------------------------
```

So far I have done large job in PHP. With one query I get all `user_id` where `date` is older then 2 days, then through `mysqli->fetch()` for every row I do `UPDATE` query and set for that user active to 0.

Now I want to put this in one query with bulk method (friend recomend it to me, cause I have 10.000+ users), but I am not sure how the query should look like.

```
$query = ""; // help me with this line of code
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

Can you help me with query, cause all things I tried wont work.

Comment: Start here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html    ``... where `date` <= now() - interval 2 day`` or something similar.

Comment: is there only one record per user in the login table ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine the queries. You're selecting the id's with the first query. So place that in your where clause of the update query.

```
update users set active = 0 where active = 1 and id in (select user_id from login where date <= now() - interval 2 day)
```

This will deactivate all users with a login date older than 2 days.